# プライベート・ベータに関するヘルプが日本語版スタック・オーバーフローに新設されたのは何故ですか？

Tags: サポート, ヘルプ

ヘルプセンターにプライベート・ベータに関するヘルプが出来ていました

- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask-beta

現在日本語版スタック・オーバーフローはパブリック・ベータで、プライベート・ベータではありません。このヘルプの必要性がよく分からないのですが、なぜ存在するのでしょうか？

参考: このヘルプは英語版 Stack Overflow にも存在します。https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask-beta

---

English version: A help page about private beta was created even though Stack Overflow in Japanese is in public beta, not in private beta. I don't know why this help is needed. Is there any reasons to create this help? I want to translate all help pages, so I want to know the background of this help page.

Comment: This help entry is listed on all sites, including some sites that never had Private Beta: [“How to Ask Questions in Private Beta” is listed in every site’s help centre](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290401/241919)

Comment: "Avoid “easy” questions"、"Think like an expert"、"You get the site you build "の3箇所は日本語訳のストリングが存在するので新設されたのかどうかは不明なのですが、このページ全体を日本語訳にするのは少しホールドさせていただいてもよろしいでしょうか？ニックさんに確認させてください m_ _m

Comment: SOスペイン語版での[ニックさんの回答](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3846/101630)を見つけました!

Comment: [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290401/314875)だけでなく、[SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342473/7493042)、[Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/16810)、[Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4855)などでも類似の質問があったようですね｡ﾟ(ﾟ´Д｀ﾟ)ﾟ｡

Answer (score 3):

プライベート・ベータ版に関するヘルプ記事が存在する理由は、本ページをサイト毎に削除することがシステム上不可能であるから、とのことです。

ニックさんが以前に[Stack Overflowスペイン語版](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3847/101630)にてこの記事を削除できない理由を以下のように説明されていました。

> 要約： これは全てのStack Exchangeサイトに影響を与える包括的な質問であり、私（ニコラス）はなぜこのようになるのかを正確に把握しているわけではありませんが、削除できない理由が2つあるように思えます。
>
> 1. ヘルプセンターの仕組みとして、多言語サイトなどで新しい記事を追加できます。既存の記事を上書きできます。ただし、MSEにすでに存在する記事を削除することができません。非表示にもできません。
> 2. すべてのStack Exchangeサイトは、エリア51にてユーザーによって作成されます。本家SO（英語版）のユーザーであっても、プライベートベータ版やパブリックベータ版での質問方法を知っておく必要があります。

---

この度、CMのニックさんより日本語版の翻訳は日本語コミュニティで改善するゴーサインを得ました。（時間がかかってしまいましたごめんなさい！）翻訳ドラフトについては[こちらのページ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3238/14055)をご覧ください。コミュニティで改善できればと思います。