# ヘルプセンター翻訳："How to Ask Questions in Private Beta?"

Tags: サポート, 完了, 翻訳, ヘルプ

ヘルプ センター > 質問にあたって
[How to Ask Questions in Private Beta?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask-beta) の翻訳案です。コミュニティで改善できればと思います。直接編集どうぞよろしくお願いします。

---

### プライベート・ベータ版での質問方法

現在、スタック・オーバーフローは**パブリック・ベータ版**ですが、このページでは一般的な**プライベート・ベータ版**での質問方法を説明します。

一時的なプライベート・ベータ期間に投稿された質問のトーンと質が極めて重要です。

プライベート・ベータ版で十分な*質の高いエキスパートレベルの質問*が作成されない場合、パブリック・ベータ版に移行できません。サイトをプライベート・ベータから一般公開されるようにするためには以下のヒントをご覧ください。

### 「簡単な」質問を避ける

「このトピックに関するお薦めの本はなんですか」や「このトピックに関するお薦めのブログはなんですか」といった、アンケート、投票、初歩的な質問など、簡単で、深い意味のない質問から始めたくなる気持ちはわかります。しかしこういった質問は、このサイトで取り扱うべき内容を反映しておらず、代表的な質問ではないため、プライベート・ベータ版には適していません。

### エキスパートの視点で考える

この分野のプロやエキスパートが実際に職場で遭遇するような、具体的な答えのある、現実的で事実に基づく質問をするようにしてください。トピックに沿った専門的な質問や回答を載せたサイトを構築すると、サイトが一般公開されたときに、*他の*エキスパートの関心を引き付けるようなコンテンツがあらかじめ用意されたサイトを提供できることになります。

### 最初が肝心

最初の質問によって、長期にわたるサイトの雰囲気とトピックが決定します。初期の質問が、あなたのコミュニティの方向性を決めるのです。また、潜在的なエキスパートが初めてあなたのサイトを訪れたときには、プライベート・ベータ版での質問内容が最初のページに掲載されます。したがって、**最初の質問は、興味深く、難しく、そして模範とすべき手本となるような内容にするよう心掛けてください**。

*上記の内容は [Asking the First Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/) を基に修正されました。*

#### 関連

- [いい「主観的」、よくない「主観的」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1485/14055)
- [Real Questions Have Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)
- [Are Some Questions Too Simple?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/)

メタで討議 »

Comment: 関連投稿: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3239/32986

Answer (score 2, accepted):

反映が完了いたしました。

[image: タイトルも反映されました]