# 「プライベート・ベータ版での質問方法」の位置を下げたい

Tags: 討議, ヘルプ

[ヘルプセンター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help)のトップページや「質問にあたって」のページで「[プライベート・ベータ版での質問方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask-beta)」が上の方に配置されています。しかしこの項目は[こちらの投稿](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2942/19110)で議論されたように現在のスタック・オーバーフロー自体とはそこまで関係が無い記事です。

したがって https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/asking の一番下に配置するのが適切ではないでしょうか。「プライベート・ベータ版での質問方法」の位置を下げ、代わりに「良い質問をするには？」などの大事な項目がより目立つようにしていただきたいです。

トップページにおける現在の表示：

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ヘルプセンターでの順番は更新順なのではという観察があり、aki さんが「再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方」と「良い質問をするには？」を更新することで上に持ち上げてくださいました。

とりあえずヘルプセンタートップページには載らなくなったので、この投稿は解決とします。

（ https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/asking の一番下にはなっていませんが、まあ良いかと思い……。問題ありそうなら他のヘルプも更新することで下に移しますが、そもそも更新順になってることの方が問題かもです。）